# Which one is correct: "the name of the X" and "the X name" or "the X's name"?

Tags: articles, definite-articles

I'd like to know if writing `the name of the variable` is necessary. Could we just write `the variable name` (if not `variable's name`) instead?

Examples:

> To reuse data, reuse **the name of the variable** that stores it.
>
> Scope is the part of the program where a particular identifier, such as a variable or **a function name** is accessible.
>
> It can lead to conflicting **names of the variables**.

Comment: Please do not ask multiple questions within one question, it causes confusion.

Comment: Hello and welcome to EL&U, which aspires to be a repository of on-topic questions and expert answers about English. We like questions to be well-researched beforehand, with the research posted with the question so that others don't have to waste time looking for things the asker already knows. To facilitate the scoring process (up/down votes), we also like questions to be focused (ask about 1 thing per question). [Here's](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/427204/142322) an answer I posted that's relevant to your Q2. If it addresses your query, consider dropping Q2 and expanding on Q1.

Comment: Hi Aduku. Can you give an example of a sentence, please? "The variable name" is OK in many cases, but sometimes it is grammatically better to say "the variable's name".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends heavily on the context.

To explain:

> To reuse data, reuse the *name* of the **variable that stores it**.

This is correct because we're talking about the *name* (a property) of the "variable that stores the data".

> To reuse data, reuse the **variable's name that stores it**.

This is *incorrect* because now we're saying its the *name* (that belongs to the variable) storing the data.

> To reuse data, reuse the **variable name that stores it**.

This is *incorrect* because we're still saying the *variable name* (as a thing) stores the data.

> Scope is the part of the program where a particular identifier, such as a variable or a **function name is accessible**.

This is correct because we're saying the *function name* (as a thing) is accessible.

> Scope is the part of the program where a particular identifier, such as a variable or a **function's name is accessible**.

This is correct, and is basically identical to the sentence above. We're saying the *name* (that belongs to a function) is accessible.

> It can lead to **conflicting names of the variables**.

This is *grammatically* correct but very badly written. We're saying there are "conflicting names" that are properties of the "variables", but this makes it sound like *all* variables have names that are conflicting.

> It can lead to **conflicting variable names**.

This is correct and makes much more sense than the sentence above. Now, it is clear that we are talking about the *variable names* (as things) conflicting with each other.

**Source**: Native speaker & author. Hobbyist coder.

---

---

**EDIT: Detailed answer to an example from the comments:**

> The book's title is confusing when compared to the **content of the book**.

This is correct because we are saying the *title* (that belongs to the book) is confusing when compared to the *content* (a property) of the book.

> The book's title is confusing when compared to the **book's content**.

This is correct because we are still saying the *title* (that belongs to the book) is confusing when compared to the *content* (that belongs to the book).

These two sentences are very similar. In this context, they mean the same thing.

**-------------BONUS TIP---------------**

Because we have already explained that we're talking about the title that belongs to *the book*, we don't need to explain that the content **also** belongs to *the book*. Instead, we can use the possessive form of the generic noun "it" and say:

> The book's title is confusing when compared to **its content**.

This is correct because we are saying the *title* (that belongs to the book) is confusing when compared to the *content* (that belongs to **it**). We can assume that "it" = *the book* because we are not talking about any other objects.

**Note**: Be careful to not confuse "**its**" with "**it's**". "**Its**" is the possessive form of "it". "**It's**" is a contraction of "it is".

Comment: Thanks for your help @Hyperglyph! Hoping that I understood your answer, I tried to rewrite this sentence: _The **book's title** was confusing when compared to **the content of the book.** / **the book's content.**_. Unfortunately, I'm still not so sure about the last part...

Comment: I edited my post with a detailed explanation (at the bottom) of that sentence. I hope it helps.