# Where to use "the"

Tags: grammar, american-english, vocabulary

Which sentence is correct?
are we meeting before the class or
are we meeting before class

Comment: Neither is incorrect, though it might be more natural to leave out 'the'.

Comment: ... Perversely, "Are we meeting before the lesson?" needs the definite article.

Comment: One lesson is apparently specific. But those educated with private tutors do things _before lessons_. (I googled _princess "before lessons"_).

Answer (score 0):

When a noun is used without an article, linguists often call it a [*zero article*](https://www.englishclub.com/grammar/determiners-zero-article.htm) or *zero determiner*.

This occurs, among other reasons, for many events or places that are part of a regular routine, thus requiring no specificity.

> She wanted to run some errands before dinner.

But

> She wanted to run some errands before the dinner.

In the first sentence, *dinner* is a routine event occurring so regularly — and for most English speakers roughly at the same time, except for those who call it *tea* or *supper*— that it's often used as a time reference. In the second, a specific event is implied, such as a formal dinner at a hotel or a dinner party at her own home, i.e., a specific, not routine, event.

Your question most likely falls into this category. If a native speaker asks another

> Do you want to meet before class?

the time reference is common to both speakers' routines and need not be further specified.

If instead, a native speaker asks:

> Do you want to meet before the class?

the other may ask, "Which class?" unless the other already knows what specific class, say, a master class conducted by a famous musician, is meant.

Comment: I disagree. I'd class this as a [null article](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/239585/why-do-people-omit-the-definite-article/427204#427204), not zero article, usage. A corresponding example is 'He tends bar.'

Comment: So you're one of those linguists who don't _often_ call it _zero article_, but I linked to a reputable source that does. Argue with them, not me. Whether zero or null, the main point is that the article _isn't there_.

Comment: No. OP asks 'Where to use "the" ', not just 'Should I use "the" here?' and is asking for general guidance, which requires analysis where possible. The linked thread provides this.

Comment: Asking which of two choices requires only enough general guidance to determine in which situations the OP would say _before class_ vs. _before the class_.