# as+/-indefinite article : as a student/as student

Tags: indefinite-articles

I learned that "as cook" is correct than "as a cook" 
if their job is cook. 
So "He served as conductor of Boston Philharmonic." is also correct.
However, from http://gregmankiw.blogspot.kr/2007/03/my-life-as-student.html
he says "life as a student", thus student is not considered as job/position?
So it's correct to say "as a middle schooler"?

plus, does having an adj like 'med' student or 'first female' conductor affect indefinite articles?

Comment: I've read that link, and my question is different, and I read manuals, and I don't know how to edit on this strictly nerdy-standard site with formatting/computer terms I'm not familiar with. Editing could take tenfolds of time than putting a question..Could this be downgraded? :) It's a joke.

Comment: Just below your post there's an edit button (right below you "indefinite-article" tag).

Comment: Have a look at [an answer](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/427204/142322) I submitted to another question. It deals with Peter Master's hierarchy of zero/indefinite/definite/null articles.

Comment: So the key is whether a student is occupation/title as doctor. And that was my main question as well. And I thought I laid out my question pretty clearly. Anyway thanks for links.

Comment: Try Googling the two with quotation marks: ["as cook" has 900 thousand results](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22as+cook%22), while ["as a cook" has 6.5 million results](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22as+a+cook%22). Also note that if you were right, it would be weird to say some phrases "well as a brain surgeon, I will operate on the tumor inside your brain", wait what do you mean "as", isn't this your day job? Or using the announcement system, "well as a pilot, I'd like to ask everyone to remain calm, I'm just informing you our captain is not well and we need an emergency landing".

Comment: right on what? I think we're talking different things. Can someone let me know whether it's okay to say "as a middle school student" instead of "as middle school student"? Yes or no would do, hopefully with grammar rules I can refer to in the future.

Comment: I think you would omit the article, or use the definite article, if the occupation referred to is a particular post. "I worked as a cook for ten years" but "I worked as cook at Newtown School" (or "the cook"). So, yes, say "as a student" as they are one of many.