# USE OF AN ARTICLE "THE" WITH NOUN

Tags: grammar, word-usage, articles

I am a student of functional English. My teacher told me to search a difference between two sentences that have almost same structure except the article **"THE"**. And because of this article the meaning of both sentences differ. I have searched many websites but i don't find the appropriate answer. So help me to find the appropriate difference between these following sentences:

1: He goes to School.

2: He goes to the School.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there a reason the British omit the article when they "go to hospital"?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/19604/is-there-a-reason-the-british-omit-the-article-when-they-go-to-hospital). You will find most of the answer there, but I'd guess that your teacher is unfamiliar with the ground-breaking work of [Master](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/239585/why-do-people-omit-the-definite-article/427204#427204) looking at the 'null article' (as contrasted with the 'zero article').

Comment: A superficial answer here is that 'He goes to school' is idiomatic for 'He attends school'. It is fine as a complete sentence given sensible context, or may have a temporal and/or other qualifiers ('He goes to school by car on Thursdays'). // I'll change your second variant slightly in the interests of idiomaticity. 'He went to the school' means 'He went to the school building / premises'. It would normally be used with immediate context (eg 'He went to the school to see whether the building was still as ugly as he remembered it being'). There _is_ an overlap with ...

Comment: sense (1): 'OJ Simpson went to the school in San Francisco that Dom DiMaggio had attended', but 'the' here is specifying [the particular school that Dom DiM had attended] and this trumps the usual 'go to [no article] school' form for 'attend'. Of course, 'OJ Simpson went to the school in San Francisco that Dom DiMaggio had attended' is ambiguous (though it is a fact that they both attended the then Galileo High School). (It's also a fact that my wife and I went to [well, past] the school in San Francisco that Dom DiMaggio and OJ Simpson had attended, in 2017.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To my ears:

1: He goes to School.

implies he is likely a student or teacher who regularly goes to his school.

2: He goes to the School.

doesn't imply he is a student or teacher. He could go to that school for any purpose.