# Is it necessary to add "a" before the noun in this sentence?

Tags: grammaticality, nouns, articles, indefinite-articles

Consider the sentence fragment:

> ...as Business Development Representative, I would...

If Business Development Representative describes a role occupied by a single person (for example, "as President" instead of "as a President" or "as CEO" instead of "as a CEO"), is an "a" required to precede the noun so it reads:

> ...as **a** Business Development Representative, I would...

There is just one Business Development Representative.

Comment: How many are there?  You imply just one, so there's nothing "indefinite".

Comment: According to the analysis [Master](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/239585/why-do-people-omit-the-definite-article/427204#427204) accepts, this is the null rather than the zero article, even more definite than the definite article. 'As king, he ...'.

Comment: There is just one Business Development Representative.

Comment: @HotLicks It doesn't really matter. One or more. The indefinite article is still a contentious issue.

Comment: They do not mean the same thing. Just think about it.

Comment: @Kris -- "Business Development Representative" is capitalized.  That implies that this specific position is being discussed, and hence either the definite article or no article at all is called for.  If not capitalized it would imply the *concept* of a representative for business development (or whatever) and so the indefinite article would generally be appropriate.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why do people omit the definite article?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/239585/why-do-people-omit-the-definite-article)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should drop the article:

[1] *...as Business Development Representative, I would...*

is exactly like

[2] *...as President/treasurer/secretary/chair/[...], I would...*

Even though *President* (like *treasurer, secretary, chair*, etc.) is a count noun† in the singular, and such nouns normally require a determiner, examples like [1] and [2] are exceptional.

<sup>†*Business Development Representative* is not a single noun, but rather what [CGEL](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0521431468) calls a **nominal**. (In linguistics more broadly it would often be called an *NP'*, pronounced "NP-bar"; see e.g. [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X-bar_theory).) However, the [**head**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Head_(linguistics)) of that nominal is a count noun in the singular, *representative*, so the whole nominal therefore normally requires a determiner. In general, in what follows, everything stated about *President*, *treasurer* etc. applies also to *Business Development Representative*.</sup>

As far as *why* in examples like [1] and [2] we drop the article, there are two points—one about semantics, and one about syntax.

Semantically, *President* (*treasurer*, *chair*, etc.) refers to a 'unique role' held by a person in a particular situation. This means that the determiner should normally be dropped, **provided** the gramamtical function of *President* (and this is the syntactic point) is either that of a **predicative complement** or of a **predicative oblique**. In [2], *President* functions as a the latter, a complement of the preposition *as*, where the whose *as* phrase functions as a **marked predicative complement**.

In particular, a bare role NP cannot function as a subject or an object. You cannot say **Treasurer has resigned* or **She questioned treasurer*; you'd need some determiners, e.g. ***Our*** treasurer has resigned and *She questioned **the** treasurer*.

**Discussion**

Here is the relevant section from [Collins COBUILD English Guides: Articles](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0003705617) (pp. 51-52):

> **6.14 Special roles**
>
> Some nouns can refer to a special, unique role held by a person in a particular situation (for example, a government or business). When they are used like this, you can leave out the definite article.
>
> *...when he was **President**.*
>   *It was nearly 40 years before she became **Queen**.*
>   *...Mr John Hume, **leader** of the Social and Democratic Labour Party.*
>
> It would be unnatural to leave in the definite article and say 'when he was the President' or 'she became the Queen', although you can leave it in when the noun is followed by 'of'. Some words commonly used in this way are:
>
> author                  chairman             king                          queen
>   best man             chairperson         leader                       secretary
>   boss                      director                manager                  treasurer
>   captain                 goalkeeper          president
>   centre forward    head                     prime minister
>
> The context is very important. In a gang, one person can be 'leader'; in a football team, one person can be 'captain', 'centre forward', or 'goalkeeper'; at a wedding one person can be 'best man'; in a country one person can be 'king', 'queen', 'president', or 'prime minister'. Many other nouns can be used in this way in a particular context.
>
> Note that when you are talking about a person rather than describing someone's role you need an article.
>
> ***The President*** had issued a sympathetic reply.
>   ***The Queen*** then abandoned the project.

In

*...as President I would...*

we have a singular count noun, *President*, appearing without a determinative. This is a highly exceptional situiation, which is subject to some syntactical constraints. 
[CGEL](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0521431468) analzyes *President* in [1] as *bare role NP (noun phrase)*. Here is a relevant passage (p. 328):

> Also included in the category of NP are **bare role NPs** such as *president, deputy leader of the party*—bare in the sense that they do not contain a determiner. These qualify as NPs by virtue of occurring as the predicative complements of verbs like *be, become, appoint, elect,* but singular NPs of this kind are exceptional in that they cannot occur as subjects or objects, where a determiner such as the definite article *the* is required:
>
> [8]   i  *I'd like to be **president**.*                                        [predicative complement] 
>          ii  *I'd like to meet ***president**/**the president**.*                                     [object]

In more detail (p. 253):

> The crucial syntactic property of PC [predicative complement] is that it can have the form either of an AdjP [adjective phrase] or of a bare role NP (a count singular with no determiner, such as *President of the Republic, treasurer*, etc.). Usually it can have the form of an ordinary NP [noun phrase] too, but what distinguishes PC from O [object] is the admissibility of an AdjP or bare role NP.
>
> [5]            PREDICATIVE COMPLEMENT                                   OBJECT 
>                i  a.  *He seemed **a nice guy**/**nice**.*           b.  *He met **a nice guy**/***nice**.* 
>               ii  a.  *I consider it **bad advice**/**bad**.*         b.  *I gave her **bad advice**/***bad**.* 
>             iii  a.  *She remained **treasurer**.*                   b.  **She questioned **treasurer**.* 
>              iv  a.  *They appointed him **secretary**.*       b.  **They promised him **secretary**.*
>
> Examples [i-ii] illustrate the possibility of replacing an ordinary NP by an AdjP (adjective phrase) in the case of PC, and the impossibility of doing so with O. Examples [iii-iv] show bare role NPs functioning as PC and the ungrammaticality that results from putting them in O function: the NPs in [iiib/ivb] need determiners (e.g. *She questioned **the treasurer**; They promised him **a secretary***).
>
> The ability of AdjPs to function as PC but not O reflects the fact that a PC characteristically expresses a property, while O (like S [subject]) characteristically refers to someone or something: AdjPs denote properties but are not used referentially. Similarly, the restriction on bare role NPs reflects the fact that they too cannot be used referentially; note in this connection that they are equally excluded from subject function: ****Treasurer*** has resigned.

On p. 255, CGEL points out that a bare role NP can function as **predicative obliques**, which is exactly how it functions in [1] and [2].

> ■ Predicative obliques
>
> Predicative elements may occur as complement of a preposition instead of being related directly to the verb. Much the most common preposition is *as*:
>
> [9]                    INTRANSITIVE                                          TRANSITIVE 
>             i  a.  ***That*** counts as **excellent**.    b.  *I regard **her** as **indispensable**.*                  [AdjP]  
>            ii  a.  ***She*** served as **treasurer**.    b.  *They chose **her** as **secretary**.*         [bare role NP]
>
> Again the predicand is S [subject] in the intransitive, and normally O [object] in the transitive.<sup>30</sup> The complements of *as* we analyse as **predicative obliques**, and the *as* phrases themselves (*as excellent*, etc.) as **marked predicative complements.**
>
> <sup><sup>30</sup>The verb *strike* is exceptional in having S as predicand in a transitive construction: compare I *regard him as a 
>   liability* (normal, O as predicand) and *He strikes me as a liability* (exceptional, S as predicand). The behaviour of *strike* here correlates with its exceptional alignment of semantic roles and syntactic functions. Like *regard* it belongs to the field of cognition, yet it aligns experiencer and stimulus with O and S respectively, instead of the usual S and O (cf. §2.3), and this exceptional alignment in turn reflects the fact that the sense involved here is a secondary one relative to that of *He struck me on the chin.*</sup>

Comment: **No, don't drop the article!!**  Set it down *carefully*, so you don't break it!